# Keras neural network model accuracy is always zero

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

My name is Sabber. My research interests are in computational geophysics. Recently I have started working on a deep-learning application to geophysics. Part of this work I have played with some toy examples (spiral data) using both "Tensorflow" and "Keras." With some trial and error, I was able to get 97% accuracy. BTW, All the problems are the regression.

In this work, I want to predict any of the stress component based on some physical parameters (temperature, density, p-wave, s-wave velocity, thermal energy, and depth).

However, when I use the actual geophysical data, I got zero accuracies from the first epoch. I do not have any clue right now what made the accuracy zero. I have spent many hours to learn if I had made any mistake. I am a little bit frustrated since I could not figure out the problem. There might have a couple of options to dig:

- Either my data has nothing to learn or
- Data pre-processing is wrong.

At this stage, I feel I desperately need some help. For your convenience, I have Included:

1. Code ("Tensorflow" and "Keras" ):
   https://github.com/msahamed/deep_learning_stress_model

This repository has three files. Out of these three "ipynb" you can look at either "predict_stress_keras.ipynb" or "predict_stress_tensorflow.ipynb". The code is very straightforward. I have written all the necessary comments.

2. Data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwexgJqQoeJUVlVPUkhtT210MlE

The data file has no any header and has 11 columns. The X can be first seven columns. We do not need x coordinate (8 column). This column can be ignored. Based on X we want to predict any of the stress components (xx/xz/zz).

Update:
Even if ignore the accuracy for this regression problem, all the predicted results are same(see Figure)

[image: Accuracy and loss of the model]

[image: Test and predicted data]

Please give me some feedback. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please describe shortly content of your repo. This seems like a huge issue, try to provide details, don't make us dig through your code - you're gonna have bigger chance to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Flip Malczak, I have added some information to the post and code for your convenience. Thanks again

Comment: Accuracy is used for classification, you are doing regression, so the accuracy is completely meaningless. Zero accuracy is not a problem :)

Comment: Matias Valdenegro thanks. Still,  predicted data is all the same. Maybe my data preparation is wrong

Comment: Accuracy is also used for prediction, it just depends how you define it. In the case of regression, it's some measure of the distance between the prediction(s) and the target(s). It should not be zero!

Comment: michetonu , That's what I did for spiral toy example. And I got 97% accuracy and I plotted both prediction and test data, they fairly overlapped with each other. I do not know what's going on here in this dataset. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matias Valdenegro is right - accuracy is not meaningful in this context and a value of zero is to be expected. See this thread: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/108

Some quick recommendations regarding your code:

10 layers is way too much. Start with 2 or 3 layer max.
Start with the Keras defaults and only change where necessary.

Try sth like this and improve from there:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'tanh', input_dim = 7))
model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(units = 16, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation="linear"))
model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mean_absolute_error')

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 2048, epochs = 20, 
           validation_split= 0.2, verbose=0)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=2048)
print(score)
```